# How to validation on all form fields together?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image-uploading

I am creating a program in which a person can insert any product with its Image. The problem I am facing is that If I enter product details, and without uploading image if I click on submit button, it inserts the records.
I want it to not insert record if the User has not uploaded any image.In short I want to use Validation on Images as well. I have used (isset) with product fields but when I use (isset) with Image it gives me the following error messages and if I just remove isset($_POST['files[]']) it works perfectly fine but it stops validating Image fields.

Here I am sharing the code. The Code is quite lengthy. Any help would be appreciated.

> Plesae fill all the Fields
>   silverbrooches.jpg
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''silverbrooches.jpg',
>   'upload/products/32046silverbrooches.jpg')' at line 2
>   Gold_Ring2.png
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''Gold_Ring2.png', 'upload/products/207Gold_Ring2.png')' at line 2
>   Necklaces_Diamond.png
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''Necklaces_Diamond.png',
>   'upload/products/6748Necklaces_Diamond.png')' at line 2

```
    <?php 

    //Use Category_id insted of Sub_category_id
    session_start();
    if (isset ($_SESSION['username']) )
    {

        //echo "<div id='nav'";
        echo "<ul><hr>
         <li><a href='insert_product.php' >Add Product  </a></li>   
         <li><a href='add_category.php'> Add Category </a></li> 
          <li><a href='add_sub_category.php'> Add Sub-Category </a></li>    
         <li><a href = 'view_products.php'  >View All Products</a>  </li>
         <li><a href = 'all_categories.php'  >View All Categories</a>  </li>
           <li><a href='view_all_sub_categories.php'>View All Sub Categories</a></li>

         </ul></hr>";





    error_reporting(E_PARSE);  //To Remove Notices!!
    global $current_id;
    //$GLOBALS $current_id;


    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {


        include 'connect.php';

        //      $select_query=          'Select * from category';
        //      $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);

                echo "<div id='line' >
                       <div id='form'>";

        echo "  
            <form action='insert_product.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
            <table border=1>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <label>Product Name:</label> </td>  <td><input type='text' name='product_name'  />*Required</td></tr>

            <tr><td><label>Item No:</label></td> <td><input type='text' name='item_no' ></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Recipient   </td>   <td> <input type='text' name='recipient' ></td></tr> 

        <tr><td>    Total Carat Weight</td> <td><input type='text' name= 'total_carat_weight' ></td></tr>

        <tr><td>    Metal </td><td><input type='text' name='metal' ></td></tr>

        <tr><td>    Stone Shape </td><td><input type='text' name='stone_shape' ></td></tr>

        <tr><td>    Stone Type</td><td> <input type='text' name='stone_type'></td></tr> 

        <tr><td>    Stone Setting</td><td> <input type='text' name='stone_setting'></td></tr> 

        <tr><td>    Wastage </td><td><input type='text' name='wastage'></td></tr></br></br>

        <tr><td>    Retail_price </td><td><input type='text' name='retail_price' ></td></tr>

        <tr><td>    Actual Price: </td><td> <input type= 'text' name= 'price'  /></td></tr>*Required

        <tr><td>    Description:</td><td><input type='text' name='description'  /></td></tr>

        <tr><td>    Image1:</td><td> <input type='file' name= 'files[]' ></td></tr> *Required

        <tr><td>    Image2:</td><td> <input type='file' name= 'files[]' ></td></tr>

        <tr><td>    Image3:</td><td> <input type='file' name= 'files[]' ></td></tr></table> ";




        /*------------------
        Drop Down List Start
        ------------------  */      

                        /*----------------
                        Drop Down List
                        ---------------*/



                    echo "<select name='category'>";

                    $select_query=          'Select * from category';
                    $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);

                    $sub_category_query="Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='".$select_query_array['category_id']."'";

                //   $sub_category_query="Select * from sub_categories ";
                //   $sub_query_run=         mysql_query($sub_category_query);


                            while ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) ) {

                                     echo "<optgroup label='".$select_query_array['name']."' >".

                                            //$sub_category_query="Select * from sub_categories";
                                            $sub_category_query="Select * from sub_categories 
                            where category_id='".$select_query_array['category_id']."'";                                        

                                            $sub_query_run=         mysql_query($sub_category_query);

                                    while   ($sub_query_run_fetch=   mysql_fetch_array($sub_query_run) ) {
                                        echo "<option value='".$sub_query_run_fetch['sub_category_id'] . "' >" .
                                        htmlspecialchars($sub_query_run_fetch['sub_category_name']) . "</option>";
                                                     }
                                            echo "</optgroup>";
                         }
                     echo "</br>";

                     $selectTag= "</br><input type='submit' value='Insert Product'  /></select></form>";

                     echo "</div></div>";

                     echo $selectTag;

    /*----------------
    Drop Down List
    ---------------*/


        /*-----------------
        Drop Down List End
        ------------------*/    









if(isset($_POST['product_name']) && isset($_POST['price']) &&  isset($_POST['description'] )
        && isset($_POST['files[]'])
             )
        {
             $product_name  =       $_POST['product_name'];
             $price         =       $_POST['price'];
             $description   =       $_POST['description'];
             $category      =       $_POST['category'];









        $query= "insert into products (name, sub_category_id ) 
                    VALUES( '$product_name', $category )";


        if($query_run=      mysql_query($query) )
        {

            echo 'Data Inserted';
            $current_id=     mysql_insert_id();
            //$_SESSION['current_id']= mysql_insert_id();



            }   
            else
            {
                'Error In SQL'.mysql_error();
                }



        /*-----------------
        INSERT Description!!
        -------------------*/
        $item_no=               $_POST['item_no'];
        $recipient=             $_POST['recipient'];
        $total_carat_weight=    $_POST['total_carat_weight'];
        $metal=                 $_POST['metal'];
        $stone_shape=           $_POST['stone_shape'];
        $stone_type =           $_POST['stone_type'];
        $stone_setting  =       $_POST['stone_setting'];
        $wastage        =       $_POST['wastage'];
        $retail_price   =       $_POST['retail_price'];






        $query_description= "insert into product_description VALUES($current_id,'$item_no','$recipient',
                            '$total_carat_weight','$metal','$stone_shape','$stone_type','$stone_setting',
                                     '$wastage','$retail_price','$price' ,'$description'    ) ";

                                    if(mysql_query($query_description))
                                    {
                                        echo 'Insert descrition successfull';
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo mysql_error();
                                            }





        }


        else
        {
            echo '</br>Plesae fill all the Fields';
            }



                /*-----------------
                IMAGE QUERY 2
                ------------------*/


        if (isset($_FILES['files'])
    ||  ($_FILES["files"]["type"]   == "image/jpeg"))
    {

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key=> $tmp_name)
        {
            //echo $tmp_name."<br>";

        echo    $image_name=        $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];  

            $random_name=       rand().$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

            $folder="upload/products/" .$random_name;                       

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],
                        "upload/products/" . $random_name);


        //  print_r($_FILES);


            $sql = "Insert into product_images (product_id,name,images) 
                            VALUES ($current_id,'$image_name', '$folder')";

                            if (mysql_query($sql))
                            {
                                echo 'Done';
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    echo mysql_error();
                                    }


        }

    }





                /*-----------------
                IMAGE QUERY 2- END
                ------------------*/




}


else
{
    echo 'You Must Log in To View this Page!';
    }
}

else
{
    echo "You Must need to login to View this Page";

    }
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST` brings all inputs where as for files you need to use `$_FILES` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: also dont use `isset()` rather check `if ($_FILES['name'] != "")`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated my code, now its not giving me any error message but still if I insert data without uploading image, it inserts data.  ` if(isset($_POST['product_name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])
 && $_FILES['files'] != ""`

Comment: either use `$_FILES['files']['name']` or `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']`,

Comment: `$_FILES['files']` is actually an array

Comment: I have just noticed a new problem. If i just press 'Insert' button without inserting any record, it inserts record in the database and give me the message 'Records Inserted'

Comment: Yes because you are checking `isset()`.. `isset` will always return true if you already have form field for it, EG. `<input type='text' name='fname'>` and you check `isset($_POST['fname'])` since it is set it will not check if your textbox is empty or not.

Comment: You need to check it in the same way you did for file i.e. `if (trim($_POST['fname']) != "")` so if the user left the field empty your code will stop there and will go into the else..

Comment: PS: `trim()` will actually trim the white spaces from both side.. from the beginning and from the end..

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, you can now select the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` brings all inputs where as for files you need to use `$_FILES` 
check this php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Also don't use `isset()` rather check `if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != "")` because `isset` will always return true if you have the field with the name in your html form 
**for e.g.** `<input type='text' name='fname'>` and if you check `isset($_POST['fname'])` it will return true since it is already set at `name='fname'`

`isset` will not check if your textbox is empty or not. you can use

```
if (trim($_POST['fname']) != "") {

} else {

}
```

so if the user left the field empty your code will stop there and will go into the else block.

**PS:** `trim()` will [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the white spaces from start and end of the string..

Answer (score 0):

The $_FILES['fileFormName'] has an index called 'error' which does the trick.

```
if($_FILES['files']['error'][0] == 4){
     echo you didn't upload an image
}
```

This will check if the user has uploaded the image.

the [0] is the **Imagen 1** in the files array, it's an array because you are using files[] in the form.

You can use if with **or** or **and** statement to play, if you want the user "have to" to upload **ALL** images use this

```
if($_FILES['files']['error'][0] == 4 or $_FILES['files']['error'][1] == 4 or $_FILES['files']['error'][2] == 4){ echo "You must upload ALL images";}
```

just change from **or** to **and** to require only atleast one image